# Question about prompt names of ordinals

Tags: set-theory, forcing

The following concept is due to Shelah and I have some issues with a claim using this notion:
Suppose that $\nu$ is a limit ordinal and that $P_\nu$ is an iteration of forcing notions. We say that a $P_\nu$ name $\dot{\alpha}$ of an ordinal is $prompt$ iff the following two things hold:

1. $\Vdash_\nu \dot{\alpha} \le \nu$
2. If $p \Vdash_\nu "\dot{\alpha} = \xi"$ then even $p \upharpoonright \xi ^\smallfrown 1_\nu \upharpoonright [\xi, \nu) \Vdash_\nu \dot{\alpha} = \xi$  ( $1_\nu$ should be the largest element of the iteration, and $\xi$ is the hacek name of an ordinal though I refused to write the hacek)

Then the following two things should hold:

1. If $\dot{\alpha}$ is prompt $\eta \le \nu$ and if $p \Vdash_\nu \eta \le \dot{\alpha}$ then $p \upharpoonright \xi ^\smallfrown 1_\nu \upharpoonright [\xi, \nu) \Vdash_\nu \eta \le \dot{\alpha}$
2. If $\dot{\alpha_i}$ are prompt then so is the supremum $sup$ and the minimum $min$

I have problems proving those two assertions so any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: By $p|\xi\frown 1_\nu | [\xi,\nu)$ you mean the condition $q$ which agrees with $p$ up to $\xi$ and it has constant value the largest element after $\xi$.

Comment: I would suggest that nontrivial questions about forcing are better placed on mathoverflow. (And this would seem especially true for questions about iterated forcing.)

Comment: It was suggested in a moderator flag that this question be migrated to MathOverflow. Just wanted to explain that MathOverflow is not a part of the SE 2.0 network ([or at least, not yet](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1082/migrate-to-se-20)), so question migration is not possible - it would have to be reposted by hand.

Comment: Ok, its now posted on MO

Comment: Posted on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/87976/question-about-prompt-names-of-ordinals

Comment: Seeing how it was answered (twice!) on MO, I'm voting to close this. Also, it's a shame you're not coming to Italy after all! I'll see you in September, I hope!